# Jenkins LTS Docker image stuck on Jenkins 2.60.3

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile

I have a image "x/jenkins-base" using

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

which is used by another one using

```
FROM x/jenkins-base
```

Now, despite doing

```
docker pull jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

The image seems to be stuck at Jenkins 2.60.3.

The [jenkins/jenkins Dockerfile on GitHub](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/Dockerfile) indeed still references 2.60.3.

So how can I update to the latest LTS (today at 2.89.1)?

Comment: When did you do the pull? Seems like the lts tag was pushed [2 hours ago](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins/tags/)

Comment: @tkausl - Jenkins is notorious for overwriting their tags with the same version. They do the same with their `blueocean` image and any others I've seen. It's insanely annoying.

Answer (score 1):

If their `lts` tag is that version; then you can't do anything about that. What you can do - is build your own image!

Take that Dockerfile you just pasted, and on [line 40](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/Dockerfile#L40) you'll see they have an `ARG` for setting the version - that you pointed out.

You can build with a different version by using the `--build-arg` option in order to pass this.

```
docker build --build-arg 2.89.1 -t custom-jenkins .
```

It looks like it then uses that variable to download the `.war` file from their servers, so I'd double check that file is actually available for the version you want; which looks like [it is.](https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/org/jenkins-ci/main/jenkins-war/2.89.1/jenkins-war-2.89.1.war)

Answer (score 0):

You need to rebuild your images using `docker build --pull` to bring the newest `FROM` images, from top to bottom